# Can not scale up the QIcon

Tags: qt

I have this code;

```
void FileBrowser::setItemIcon(QStandardItem *item)
{
    // check whether its a file or not
    QFileInfo fileInfo(item->text());

    if(fileInfo.suffix() == "cpp")
    {
        QPixmap pxm("icons/cpp.svg");
        pxm.scaled(QSize(48, 48), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
        QIcon icon(pxm);
        item->setIcon(icon);
    }
}
```

The icons do not scale up. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The QPixmap::scaled member function is const - i.e. it doesn't change the object itself.
The scaled object is returned by that method, it doesn't change the original pixmap.

Try something like:

```
QPixmap bgPixmap(fileName);
QPixmap scaled = bgPixmap.scaled( QSize(48, 48), Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation );
QIcon icon(scaled);
item->setIcon(icon);
```

Comment: Amani -- given that both myself and @Sirius have provided what is, essentially, the same solution -- I think the problem must lie elsewhere.  Can you save the unscaled and scaled pixmaps to files and check them with an image viewer or similar.

Answer (score 2):

`QPixmap::scaled` *returns* a scaled version of the pixmap rather than scaling it in-situ.  Try...

```
pxm = pxm.scaled(QSize(48, 48), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
```

Comment: Does not seem to work. The icons I'm using are SVG's of 32x32, but in my program they look smaller.

Comment: You say ''they look smaller''.  *Are* they smaller?  The updated code works just fine for me on the svg files I've tried.  Are you sure the `QStandardItem` isn't resizing/scaling the icon itself?

Answer (score 1):

You can scale the QIcon directly:

```
myBtn->setIcon(QIcon(R"(..\assets\icon.png)"));
myBtn->setIconSize(QSize(25,25));
myBtn->resize(QSize(25,25));
```